# Creating hierarchical tables in markdown

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I want to build a complex table like this:

```
| some thing | more important | up here |
|------------|----------------|---------|
| a  |a1     | b     |d       | c       |
|------------|----------------|---------|
| 1  |2      | 1     |2       |         |
```

Is it possible using gf-markdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible with GFM, however, it is possible with raw HTML.

The spec for GitHub Flavored Markdown is [here](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-). It does not appear that there is support for such a table construct. Notably, the following is stated:

> The header row must match the delimiter row in the number of cells. If not, a table will not be recognized...
>
> The remainder of the table’s rows may vary in the number of cells. If there are a number of cells fewer than the number of cells in the header row, empty cells are inserted. If there are greater, the excess is ignored.

That being the case, the table your provided would be interpreted as this:

```
| some thing | more important | up here |
|------------|----------------|---------|
| a          | a1             | b       |
| 1          | 2              | 1       |
```

That is, the last two cells in each row would be ignored. If may help to remember that:

> Cells in one column don’t need to match length, though it’s easier to read if they are. Likewise, use of leading and trailing pipes may be inconsistent.

Therefore, just because your table is easily understood by a human reader, the parser doesn't recognize that your columns are nicely aligned. It just counts the number of cells and ignores their actual alignment.

As an aside, while converting your table (for my example above) I noticed that you included a "[deliminator row](https://github.github.com/gfm/#delimiter-row)" between each row of the table. The "deliminator row" should only be between the header row and the first data row.

That doesn't mean it's not possible to create such a table. As the original Markdown [syntax rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html) state:

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself.

Of course, GFM [disallows various raw HTML](https://github.github.com/gfm/#disallowed-raw-html-extension-) tags for security reasons. However, `tables` are not on the list. Therefore, you should be able to create a raw HTML table in whatever structure you want.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">some thing</th>
      <th colspan="2">more important</th>
      <th>up here</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>a1</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>d</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can see an example of that table [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/waylan/a229e4e3c88122d0947ac1090c3a77c1) (see the [raw Markdown here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/waylan/a229e4e3c88122d0947ac1090c3a77c1/raw/783955495e9448c6fb1ec7fdccde465376b9e68d/raw_html_in_gfm.md)). I've even included your non-working original example for comparison.